# Bash replace character into = separated values

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do # resolve $SOURCE until the file is no longer a symlink
  DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
  SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
  [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE" # if $SOURCE was a relative symlink, we need to resolve it relative to the path where the symlink file was located
done

SCRIPT_PATH="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"/..

grep -o -P "(\w*_?)*=(\"|\').*(\"|\')" ${SCRIPT_PATH}/start.sh  > ${SCRIPT_PATH}/run.env
```

That generates a file with the contents:

```
SOME_VAR="13434"
ANOTHER_VAR="BlAH BLAH BLAH"
```

From a file that has contents:

```
asdf SOME_VAR="13434"\
     ANOTHER_VAR= "BlAH BLAH BLAH" some other strings
```

But now I want to remove (trim) ONLY the **STARTING** and **TAILING** `"` characters from the generated result. In my case the result I want it to be:

```
SOME_VAR=13434
ANOTHER_VAR=BlAH BLAH BLAH
```

Do you have any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: `sed 's/="/=/;s/"$//' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -oP '[^\s]+\s*=\s*"[^"]+"' file |sed 's/=\s*"\([^"]*\)"/=\1/'
```

`-o` matches only what's in single quotes

`-P` perl-like regexp

`[^\s]+` non-space characters

`sed` deletes quotes

Comment: This will remove **all** quotation marks instead of only the starting and trailing ones as the OP asked. Quote: _[...] I want to remove (trim) ONLY the STARTING and TAILING " characters [...]_

Comment: @MichaelJaros Edited.

Comment: I just tested your edited solution, and it does not behave accordingly. Try feeding it with the line `SOME_VAR="13="434"`. In my test, it removes the first two quotes instead of the first and the last one.

Answer (score 1):

A single `sed` call will do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/\([^=]*=\)"/\1/g' -e 's/"$//' file1 > file2
```

The first regex only matches a quotation mark immediately after the first `=`, while the second regex only matches a quotation mark at the end of the line.

It should be noted that the resulting file will throw errors if you try to source or execute it in Bash because Bash won't allow something like `ANOTHER_VAR=BlAH BLAH`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
awk '{sub(/"$/,"");sub(/="/,"=")} 1'   Input_file
```

Simply substituting the last occurrence of " with NULL and substituting =" with =. Then mentioning 1 there to print the edited/non-edited line

Comment: This snippet substitutes not every, but only the *first* occurrence of `="`, just as the OP asked.

Comment: Off course it was provided as per OP's provided sample Input_file. If OP adds some more conditions, I will more than happy to edit my solution accordingly.

Comment: Your solution is fine, my remark is just about your description.